# Use discriminated union in angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular component:

```
// some type
type FeedInfo = {
  published: true;
} | {
  error: string;
};
// some property
feedinfo: FeedInfo

<!-- template -->
<app-c1 [check]="feedinfo?.['published']"
        [error]="feedinfo?.['error']">
</app-c1>
```

yields the errors:

> Property 'published' does not exist on type 'FeedInfo'.
>
> Property 'error' does not exist on type 'FeedInfo'.

How do I avoid this without implementing a new method? The following does not work:

```
<app-check [check]="feedinfo.hasOwnProperty('published') && feedinfo['published']"
           [error]="'error' in feedinfo && feedinfo['error']"></app-check>
```